# perfect left / right padding for columns

Tags: html, css

If you have a number of block items in a list, I was wondering if there was a way to get

- 0 margin on the left,
- 0 margin on the right, and
- margins between the items in the middle

Right now on the items in the list I only know how to do this `margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;`

This way there is no margin on the left, so it matches to the left of my container, but there is always 5px space on the far right column... however I need `margin-right 5px` to get space in between my items.

Any suggestions?

```
div.container{
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    background:black;
}

div div{
    height:200px;
    width:160px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:grey;
    margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2M3/1/

Again I would like my items to be able to but up against the far left and right side of the container but also have margins to separate the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add `text-align: justify` to the `div.container` element.

Comment: interesting I didn't know about this thank you! however this makes the middle margins responsive and the right most div sticks to the right all the time but 5px away from the right. I could actually use this on another project but for this one I just need the right 5px margin taken off. It does need to be responsive because of the fluid container width...so whichever div is on the right needs to be able to go all the way to the right of the container, rather than only 5px away... maybe this is not possible without js...

Comment: Actually this may work... I put margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px; and with the justify on the parent element it actually looks nice... However is there a way to specify the min-margin of the elements? When you move the browser inward they get about 1px from each other then break...is there a way to specify how much margin to keep, while still keeping margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; so the left and right margins are still 0?

Comment: last line won't match because, like text, when you justify you don't justify last line

Answer (score 1):

I'm making another answer because it works well at centering the divs and it also matches the divs on the last line!

It requires a little knowing of the content you are using but some media queries can help you remove some extra space if you need to support multiple resolutions.

You need two things:
* The text justification (as Josh Rutherford answered) to align all lines except the last, and second
* A few invisible divs to fill the rest of the line so the browser can match the divs on the last line with the rest of the lines

The result is this: http://jsfiddle.net/wBe4F/1/, resize it so you can see the last line always matches the other lines no matter if there are 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 divs, they always match.

So, the idea is to add extra divs with height 0px to fill one more line so the browser will also justify it and all visible divs will be aligned.

You only need to think how many ".extra" divs you put at the end. I would put enough .extra divs to cover a complete line with the widest screen size you want to support, then you could add media queries to hide unneded .extra divs if they are making too much extra space at the bottom of your container div (the background color is there to show that). Resize it small enough and you'll see all that space below the original divs created by all those unneeded .extra divs. You could give them an id for each .extra div and "display: none;" some of them if the resolution is less than some values to keep that controlled.

To make the extra divs the same width as the original divs just add them to the original divs declaration:

```
.data, .extra {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #666;
}
```

and then tweak them a little to make them invisible

```
.extra {
    height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for commenting here! I figure I'de keep Josh as the answer since he has less a "Score" than you. This will definitely help fix the last line, I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks!!